# add new plugin to phonegap 3.4

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I'm trying to add new plugin (https://github.com/xu-li/cordova-plugin-wechat) to my phonegap project. but I get stuck on the installation number 1.

For number 1, they said **Add wechat lib to your project. Don't forget to add the "URL Type".** but I don't know where should I put library files to? which folder? because I know that every time I use *cordova build ios* command, it will generate new project files in platforms/ios. Should I put library files after generated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have install the required SDK. use command $ cordova platform add ios. Now add the generated files in the project folder. See if this works. Add Cordova command script file if required.